# Why are these obviously same strings not equal

Tags: ocaml, equality, string-comparison

I am trying following code:

```
open Str
let ss = (Str.first_chars "testing" 3);;
print_endline ("The first 3 chars of 'testing' are: "^ss);;
if (ss == "tes") 
  then print_endline "These are equal to 'tes'" 
  else print_endline "These are NOT equal to 'tes'"
```

However, I am getting these are NOT equal:

```
$ ocaml str.cma testing2.ml

The first 3 chars of 'testing' are: tes
These are NOT equal to 'tes'
```

Why first 3 characters pulled by `Str.first_chars` from "testing" not equal to "tes"?

Also, I had to use `;;` to make this code work (combinations of `in` and `;` which I tried did not work). What is the best way to put these 3 statements together?

Comment: Because you're using the physical equality operator `==` rather than the structural equality operator `=`. You were warned of this yesterday. You've also been told the difference between `;`, `in` and `;;`. Please read and try to understand the previous answers given to you.

Answer (score 4):

The [(==)](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html#VAL(==)) function is the physical equality operator. If you want to test whether two objects have the same contents, then you should use the structural equality operator which has one equal sign [(=)](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html#VAL(=)).

> What is the best way to put these 3 statements together?

There are no *statements* in OCaml. Only expressions, all returning values. It is like a mathematical formula, where you have numbers, operators, and functions and you combine them together into bigger formulae, e.g., `sin (2 * pi)`. The closest thing to the statement is an expression which has side effects and returns a value of type unit. But this is still expression.

Here is an example, how you can build your expression, which will first bind the returned substring to the `ss` variable, and then compute in order two expressions: an unconditional print, and a conditional print. Altogether, this will be one expression evaluating to the unit value.

```
open Str

let () = 
  let ss = Str.first_chars "testing" 3 in
  print_endline ("The first 3 chars of 'testing' are: " ^ ss);
  if ss = "tes" 
  then print_endline "These are equal to 'tes'" 
  else print_endline "These are NOT equal to 'tes'"
```

and here is how it works

```
$ ocaml str.cma test.ml 
The first 3 chars of 'testing' are: tes
These are equal to 'tes'
```